# Prove that $|P(x, y)| + 1 \geq C (x^2 + y^2) ^ a $ for P that approaches infinity

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

$P(x,y)$ is a polynomial with a following quality:
For every $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $x, y:|x| + |y| > M$ holds this inequality: $|P(x, y)| > N$.

Prove that there are constants $C, a > 0$ that for $x, y \in \mathbb{R} \ |P(x, y)| + 1 \geq C (x^2 + y^2) ^ a $.

Ive been stuck on this task for days now, please share any ideas on how to approach this.